# How the RAID0 write data?

Tags: raid, hard-drive

This is the RAID0 structure:

[image: RAID 0]

there have 3 disks,

I have a question about this,
when write data into disk, is it write disk A full, then write disk B?

or is write a little data into disk A, then write into disk B a little, then write to disk C a little?

Comment: @michaelhampton, this is not duplicate. The OP ask about different modes in RAID0 (and one of those modes is not mentioned in the Q/A you point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of RAID0 arrays.

First type is named "concatenate" and do this: fill disk A, then continue to disk B, then switch to disk C.

Second type is named "striping" and it write chunk to disk A, chunk to disk B and chunk to disk C and write chunk to disk A, chunk to disk B .... (those chunks are named stripes)